# How to prevent loss/miscount of data using File I/O with buffer/size hint Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am new to Python and writing several methods to process large log files (bigger than 5GB). THrough the research i did, I saw a lot of people using "with open" and specificying a size hint/buffer like so:

```
with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=102400) as f:
    time_data_count = 0
    logbinset = set()
    #def f(n):print('{:0b}'.format(n))  #check what non iteratable function means
    search_pattern = regex.compile(b'\d+\((.)+\)\s+\d+\((.)+\)')
    for line in f:
        if search_pattern.search(line):
            x = search_pattern.search(line)
            #print(x.group(1)+" "+ x.group(2))
            print((x.group(1)).decode())
            print((x.group(2)).decode())
```

Another method (this one always returns none for some reason. Could use some help finding out why:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    #text = []
    while True:
        memcap = f.read(102400)
        if not memcap:
            break
        text = re.search(b'\d+\(.+\)\s+\d+\(.+\)',memcap) 
        if text is None:
            print("none")
        print(text.group())
```

In these method, I am trying to extract regex patterns from a 6GB log file. My question is, I am worried using buffers to chop the file into chunks could result in situations where the line containing the pattern is chopped in half which would result in some data being missing.

**How do I make sure line intergrity is kept? How do I make sure it only breaks up my file at the end of a line? How do I make sure I don't lose data in between chunks?** Or does the "with open" and read(102400) method ensure lines are not split in half when breaking the file into chunks.

Comment: Do you expect your matches to span across lines? `\s*` match match line break chars, but if you do not expect that, just read the file without buffering.

Comment: The patterns are in one line. All of them. What I worry is the buffering splitting the match if it splits the file in a line to fit the buffer. The point of the buffering was to give a little more speed to the processing. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Well, whenever speed harms precision, I prefer precision. Do not use buffering in this case.

Comment: I was leaning towards not using it as well. It is only a 3 second speed bump but this was for a 6GB file. I wonder if it would make a bigger difference for a 10GB file if I encountered a file that big. Can you think of any workarounds for using buffer size but making sure no data is lost? Or is not using buffer size the best way? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I have not tried to solve this problem in Python, I solved it in C#, but the workaround was "ugly" and from all I can remember, I basically had to read the file twice with different buffer size. I am not sure you need this in Python taking into account the pattern requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all dont use 'rb' use just 'r' wich is used for text. 'rb' is for binary data.
the read method reads as many characters as you specify, so you woul end up with chopped lines. Use readline.

Comment: 'rb' is much faster than 'r for big files. 'r is slower for big files because Python is wasting time processing strings and encoding. And using readline in some method results in miscounts. Might be because of my logic? @nadapez

Answer (score 0):

The first variant is the correct one: set a buffer size when opening the file to get fewer read operations without loosing matches that span read blocks.

If you are concerned with runtime it would be a good idea to just search once in each line and not one search to determine if there is a match and then doing the exact same search again to get at the values:

```
regex = re.compile(rb"\d+\((.)+\)\s+\d+\((.)+\)")
with open(filename, "rb", buffering=102400) as lines:
    for line in lines:
        match = regex.search(line)
        if match:
            print((match.group(1)).decode())
            print((match.group(2)).decode())
```

The `for` loop and the filtering can be moved into functions that are implemented in C (in CPython):

```
regex = re.compile(rb"\d+\((.)+\)\s+\d+\((.)+\)")
with open(filename, "rb", buffering=102400) as lines:
    for match in filter(bool, map(regex.search, lines)):
        print((match.group(1)).decode())
        print((match.group(2)).decode())
```

On a 64 bit Python you could also try the `mmap` module to map the file into memory and apply the regular expression to the whole content.

Comment: Doesn't the buffer still chop up the file into chunks regardless? Meaning that you still run into the possibility of patterns being split in between chunks which could net you less results? @BlackJack

Comment: I really like the speed gain of buffer but even here, you still might miss patterns that span blocks no? @BlackJack

Comment: No it doesn't. You could test that easily yourself with a very small buffer size that is lower than the line length, say 5 bytes.

Comment: How come it never misses any patterns even those that are split in between chunks? What in the logic ensures that data integrity is maintained? could you please explain @BlackJack

Comment: Because you are reading lines, i.e. data until there is a line ending found, and searching in that lines. If there's no line ending within the currently buffered content, the file object will read more content until a line ending is found. For CPython you can find the gory details in the [_buffered_readline() function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a21e57fe55076c77b0ee454e1994ca544d09dc0/Modules/_io/bufferedio.c#L1069).

Comment: But we are using "with open()" method not readline() or readlines() so its not really reading the file into lines. lines is just an iteratable we are using no? a list? What about read() function. If you add a buffer, doesn't that also run the risk of chopping of files. @BlackJack

Comment: You are iterating over the file object which ends up in the C function I've linked in my previous comment. This has nothing to do with the `read()` method on the file object, nor with the `readlines()` method. Iterating a file objects iterates over the lines. Regardless of the `buffering` argument and of course without loosing data. If this would loose data, then iterating over a file would be pretty useless, don't you think‽